# $location not changing the path in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

I am new for AngularJS and I'm having issue with moving one page to another and I have to pass parameters from main page to details page, I followed below code but it's not working and I am getting error:

> ReferenceError: $location is not defined at a.$scope.moveToOthers (showOrders.js:4)

### app.js:

```
var sampleApp = angular.module('sampleApp', ["ngRoute"]);
sampleApp.config(['$routeProvider',
    function ($routeProvider) {
        $routeProvider.

            when('/AddNewOrder', {
                templateUrl: 'templates/add_orders.html',
                controller: 'AddOrderController'
            }).

            when('/ShowOrders', {
                templateUrl: 'templates/show_orders.html',
                controller: 'ShowOrdersController'
            }).

            when('/ExpandOrders', {
                templateUrl: 'templates/expand_orders.html',
                controller: 'ExpandOrderController'
            }).

            when('/OthersPage:id?', {
                templateUrl: 'templates/others_page.html',
                controller: 'OthersPageController'
            }).

            otherwise({
                redirectTo: '/AddNewOrder'
            });

    }]);
```

### show_orders.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
<script src="controllers/othersPage.js"></script>
<title>AngularJS Routing example</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Show orders</h1>
<button ng-click="moveToOthers()" type="button" class="btn btn-default" style="margin:10px 0px 10px 0px;">Others Page</button>
</body>
</html>
```

### showOrders.js:

```
sampleApp.controller('ShowOrdersController', function ($scope, $location) {
    $scope.msg = 'This is Show orders screen123';
    $scope.moveToOthers = function () {
        $location.path('/others_page/100')
    }
});
```

Comment: help me with code please i am begginer

Comment: try writing it as `when('/OthersPage/:id', {` and use `$location.path('/OthersPage/100')`

Comment: ReferenceError: $location is not defined at a.$scope.moveToOthers (showOrders.js:4) i am getting this error

Comment: ah, right, you didn't inject it in your controller: `('ShowOrdersController', function ($scope, $window, $location) {`

Comment: when i tapped on button Uncaught TypeError: angular.module(...).info is not a function and its redirecting to AddNewOrder page

Comment: it redirects you there because of `otherwise` (it can't find a valid URL), there is an error with the URL  you are using. from the update I say that you need to change `others_page` to `OthersPage`, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest this:

1. Correct your router: change `'/OthersPage:id?'` to `'/OthersPage/:id'`
2. On the `<button>` element don't use a function to change your path. Use instead an `ng-href` like this: `<a ng-href="/OthersPage/100" type="button" class="btn btn-default" style="margin:10px 0px 10px 0px;">Others Page</a>`

Comment: is there any benefit on using `ng-href` than using `$location.path` in controller ?

Comment: Well, in my opinion is not good to write a method to change path, unless you have to do some checks or other specific stuff before the route change. It's not good for SEO to have redirects on scripts, too. In case you are using an ng-repeat is useful to use an  ng-repeat instead of a method to do the redirect.